# How to export .so symbols from Python code

Tags: python, c++

I need to code some functionality in Python 3.8 and comply to a given C++ Interface. The code should replace an existing `.so` file which exposes this interface that is defined in a C++ header.

Here's the two options I considered so far:

1. Building a wrapper `.so` file by coding it in C++ including the interface header and delegating each call to Python with `PyEval_CallObject(...)`
2. Using Cython to compile an `.so` from a `.pyx` trying to export the needed symbols

Option 1 would most probably work, but seems a lot of work for a dumb wrapper. There must be a better way.
I couldn't get option 2 to work, and I don't know if that's possible at all.

Happy to hear about any other ideas and hints.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I picked 1. as the solution but using a nice library called `pybind11` (https://github.com/pybind/pybind11). It really simplifies both interfacing Python from c++ and c++ from Python especially when it comes to type conversions. In this way the wrapper `.so` file became really small.